# Change LAST_NUMBER value in a sequence (NEXTVAL)

Tags: oracle, sequence

My question seems easy but i haven't found a solution.
I'm using the nexval sequence in a insert SQL script but we have errors because the LAST_NUMBER value haven't been updated and its value is not correct with tabla data. For this case for example the value is 5 and the table has 62 rows.

I've searched on google but don't found the command or the way yo change the LAST_NUMBER parameter of the sequence.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE rs2qnes0 START WITH 62;
```

or `ALTER SEQUENCE rs2qnes0 LAST_NUMBER 62;` don't work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change increment by, select next value, set increment back to original value:

```
SQL> create sequence s1 start with 5;

Sequence created.

SQL> select last_number from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'S1';

LAST_NUMBER
-----------
          5

SQL> alter sequence s1 increment by 57;

Sequence altered.

SQL> select s1.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
        61

SQL> alter sequence s1 increment by 1;

Sequence altered.

SQL> select last_number from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'S1';

LAST_NUMBER
-----------
         62
```

Or use `RESTART`:

```
SQL> alter sequence s1 restart start with 77;

Sequence altered.

SQL> select last_number from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'S1';

LAST_NUMBER
-----------
         77
```

Comment: Doesn't work for system-generated sequences (identity columns).

Answer (score -1):

This post is for changing Last Number :)

Let us assume LAST_NUMBER in seq xyz is **3953** and you want to change it to **205233**, then you need to increment the sequence by (**205233 - 3953 = 201,280**) and then increment it by 1. that can be achieved by below statements:

to change the LAST_NUMBER to

```
ALTER SEQUENCE xyz INCREMENT BY 201280;
SELECT xyz.nextval from dual;
ALTER SEQUENCE xyz INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Now the LAST_NUMBER would be updated as **205233**